# IndexOutOfBoundsException при создании еще 1го экземпляра класса

Tags: java, классы

Здравствуйте. Есть код класса при котором всё работает прекрассно когда один экземпляр, а когда создается второй то выдает `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Вот код, здесь вычисляется кросс-корреляционная функция

```
public class Data {

    LinkedList <Double> X, Y, cloneX, cloneY;
    private LinkedList <Double> dataLeft = new LinkedList();
    private LinkedList <Double> dataRight = new LinkedList();
    private int size;
    Data(LinkedList <Double> X, LinkedList<Double> Y) {
        this.X = X;
        cloneX = (LinkedList)X.clone();
        cloneY = (LinkedList)Y.clone();
        this.Y = Y;
        this.size = X.size();
    }

    public double getPearsonCorrelation(LinkedList<Double> X, 
                                        LinkedList<Double> Y) {
        double result = 0;
        double sum_sq_x = 0;
        double sum_sq_y = 0;
        double sum_coproduct = 0;
        double mean_x = X.get(0);
        double mean_y = Y.get(0);

        for (int i = 2; i < X.size() +1; i += 1) {
            double sweep = Double.valueOf(i - 1) / i;
            double delta_x = X.get(i - 1) - mean_x;
            double delta_y = Y.get(i - 1) - mean_y;
            sum_sq_x += delta_x * delta_x * sweep;
            sum_sq_y += delta_y * delta_y * sweep;

            sum_coproduct += delta_x * delta_y * sweep;

            mean_x += delta_x / i;
            mean_y += delta_y / i;
        }

        double pop_sd_x = (double) Math.sqrt(sum_sq_x / X.size());
        double pop_sd_y = (double) Math.sqrt(sum_sq_y / Y.size());

        double cov_x_y = sum_coproduct / X.size();

        result = cov_x_y / (pop_sd_x * pop_sd_y);
        return result;
    }

    public void  crossCorrelationData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if (Math.abs(getPearsonCorrelation(X,Y))==1) continue;

            dataLeft.add(Math.abs(getPearsonCorrelation(X,Y)));
            X.removeFirst();
            Y.removeLast();

            if (Math.abs(getPearsonCorrelation(cloneX,cloneY))==1) continue;
            dataRight.add(Math.abs(getPearsonCorrelation(cloneY,cloneX)));

            cloneY.removeFirst();
            cloneX.removeLast();
        }
    }


    public LinkedList<Double> getDataRight() {
        return dataRight;
    }

    public LinkedList<Double> getDataLeft() {
        return dataLeft;
    }
}
```

При создании

```
Data d = new Data (sd,compress);
d.crossCorrelationData();
```

Всё прекрасно, правильные значения и т.д.
А вот когда сделаешь

```
Data d = new Data (sd,compress);
d.crossCorrelationData();
Data d1 = new Data (sd,fdim);
d1.crossCorrelationData();
```

Для первого объекта выполняется, а дальше получается ошибка.
Причем если убрать первый объект, то соответственно второй работает нормально.

Comment: Ошибка-то какая? Какое имя исключения, какой трейс? Что такое fdim?

Answer (score 1):

Аргумент `sd` (`X`) изменяется внутри `Data.crossCorrelationData` - `X.removeFirst();`, соответственно, содержимое списка во время `d1.crossCorrelationData();` отличается от того, что было в `d.crossCorrelationData();`.